# Need help for understanding pointer semantics

Tags: c, pointers

See the following piece of code and my explanation of the result.

```
void f (int * p, int * q)
{
    p = q;
    *p = 2;
}

int i = 0;
int j = 1;

int main ()
{
    f(&i, & j);

    printf("%d %d\n", i, j);

    return 0; 
}
```

We have two global variable `i` and `j` and we pass the pointer of these two variables to the function `f`.  When we do `p = q`, we actually loose the reference of `i`, and we get two pointers namely `p` and `q` both pointing to `j`. then when we do `*p = 2`, we actually change the value of `j` to `2`.

However, as we lost the reference of `i` in the step `p = q`, in the main program, the value of `i` that gets printed is the global variable that is `0`. Hence we get the result as `i = 0` and `j = 2`.

please tell me if it is a right explanation...

Now another question is when we do `p = q` in the function f, will it create a memory leak because the value previously pointed by p will be inaccessible.

Comment: "will it create a memory leak because the value previously pointed by p will be inaccessible..." : it wil be inacceccible only in function `f`. but it is still accessible in the main. the varialbles p and q exist only in `f`, not in main or other function.

Comment: The [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com) is an excellent resource.  Section 4 discusses pointers.

Comment: this was a simple question...check cfaq before asking here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `p = q` in the function only changes the local variable `p`, so `i` remains unaffected, and `&i` in `main` is still the same as before calling function. Also, you can only have memory leaks when you use `malloc()` or `calloc()` without a corresponding `free()` (including equivalent use of `realloc()`).

Otherwise, your explanation is correct.

Comment: You can actually also have memory leaks in static memory: `const char* ptr = "hello"; ptr = "world";`

Comment: @Lundin that doesnt count as a leak because nothing you do could "fix" it, right?

Comment: Just as with a dynamic memory leak, the only solution is to not write bugs in your code.

Comment: @Lundin in that example what would be the correct way to do it? Also, that will only "leak" one time, not every time that piece of code is executed, so it's not a serious leak at all such as forgetting to `delete` something `new`ed, which leaks every time the `new` is executed

Comment: The correct way would be to declare a const array to hold each string literal, then have the pointers point at that array rather than directly at the string literal.